# Angular Animate slide pages in from right and out to right side (nganimate)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm working on a school project using Angular.js. We also have to implement some animations in our website. Since my website is kind of master-detail, I would like to slide the detail page (which is a separately routed page) to slide in from right. This is not really a problem. But when I would go back to the 'master' page the master page would slide in from right. I'd much rather like the master page to slide in from left.

Is there any way to get a specific ng-view animation depending on the page? I'd like to use CSS animations but that's more of a detail.

I'm working with an index.html page with an ng-view in which a template gets loaded according to which page is navigated to.

Hope anyone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an article about animations on ng-View:
http://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview

You simply have to add a class on the ng-view container

```
<div class="page {{ pageClass }}" ng-view></div>
```

and in your Controllers

```
$scope.pageClass="pageName";
```

Comment: Yep! Just found it too and tried to implement it, although I don' get any errors, it doesn't work. When I inspect the element I see that the class is not applied where {{pageClass}} is defined. I suspect this is because my controller is only accessible in my template so the variables aren't accessible outside the inner <div> of my template?

Comment: I've found the solution! Instead of defining the controller in my HTML like so: `<div ng-controller="~Controller~">` I had to do it in my routing like so: `$routeProvider.when('/rooms', {
            templateUrl: 'views/rooms.html',
            controller: 'RoomsController'
        })`! Great!

Comment: I supposed you have done it that way because i am used to do it that way

Comment: Yes indeed, but it's a small change luckily!