# How to make different pages look like a single page being slided up and down?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have a requirement and i am not able to think how to implement in angular js. I have implemented a website where i have multiple pages, each page having its own controller.

There is a continue button at the bottom of each page. On clicking the button, the current page should vanish in such a way that it slides up and a new page should appear to the user from the bottom. Itshould appear to the user that he has acrolled to the bottom section of the page though the user has travelled to a different page.

I have not provided any code and i am also not asking dor any direct code. If you get any such example from code pen then that would be great.

Please let me know if you did not get the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648895/angular-animate-slide-pages-in-from-right-and-out-to-right-side-nganimate

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan this is what i was looking for. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it with ngAnimate. Link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate.

Everything is explained in the documentation. It's really simple to use. You basically define styles ( css ) when the page is leaving ( .ng-leave ) and enterering ( .ng-leave ).

There are some examples in the docs.

Comment: Great!!! I did not know I will get replies so soon. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it :-)